# Get Public IP Address, Lan IP Address & MAC Address of Client's Machine in MVC 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

How to get **Public IP Address, Lan IP Address & MAC Address** of Client's Machine in MVC 4?

I am trying to get IP Address of client Machine. `Request.UserHostAddress`gives the Lan IP address but

- what about Global IP Address?
- How to get Public IP Address?
- How google, whatismyip.com and so many other sites picks our Public IP with address and etc. ?

Comment: You can only get the Lan IP address if you're on the same Lan. Similarly, internet based services can only see the public IP Address, because you access them over the internet. And you can only see the MAC address if you're on the same network link. You're asking for 3 different pieces of information that all operate at completely different levels. What actual problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Given your [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21751402/get-public-ip-address-lan-ip-address-mac-address-of-clients-machine-in-mvc-4#comment32901883_21751542) asking _"How to uniquely Identify the visitor?"_, I'd say this is the same question as [How to uniquely identify the client machine in an ASP.NET application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609316/how-to-uniquely-identify-the-client-machine-in-an-asp-net-application).