# A good unique identifier as default values in MVC models?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, default-value, mac-address

In order to avoid duplicate entries from same machine that access the WebApp, I am currently looking for the least complex unique identifier as the default values in my MVC models (besides ID).

I am thinking on using MAC (assume it is on same network) as default values. But I don't know how to set it up.

Comment: Do you want to use [dynamic IP restrictions](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/dynamic-ip-restrictions) or 
your task is user identification?

Comment: Maybe Guid will work for you. It is Unique across machines too

Comment: The question is not specific enough. Are you saying you only want to allow one concurrent session from one computer?

Comment: Hi guys, my purpose is just to avoid duplicate entries from same machine into the database. If Guid can do the work, then it is great!

Comment: Please specify what you really mean by "duplicate"? Are you afraid of duplicate id if you use int values?

Comment: @SirRufo I just want to prevent same machine being added into the database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to uniquely identify the client machine in an ASP.NET application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609316/how-to-uniquely-identify-the-client-machine-in-an-asp-net-application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a user control to solve this. The problem is it the user or machine? Machine you already said, with MAC address you can do the trick. But your question is a little open, I'm in doubt. You can just check on database for any entries and just replace with the update data. If the acces is really a problem, you can compare and block.

Hope it helps. It's just an overview.

Comment: If I want to use MAC, any solution on how to add that as a value into a field models?

Comment: I don't know if iI get the question right, but I think you just have to save as a String like and compare every time that a new connection is made, so, do your code and make whatever you want to implement; :)